# AtTask REST API 'OR' Query?

Tags: attask

Is there any way to perform an 'OR' on the same field in the query string. I'm trying to search for project status of  either current 'CUR' or a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this by prefixing OR:a: before the different clauses.

```
status=CUR
status+Mod=eq
OR:a:status=PLN
OR:a:status_Mod=eq
```

continue if required

```
OR:b:...
```

Note that each block is run independently of any other.  This means that you need to repeat anything that is in common with all of them. The OwnerID would need to be in each block like below.

```
status=CUR
status+Mod=eq
ownerID=$$USER.ID
ownerID_Mod=eq
OR:a:status=PLN
OR:a:status_Mod=eq
OR:a:ownerID=$$USER.ID
OR:a:ownerID_Mod=eq
```

Via the API the lines would be separated by & not CR/LF

In the case of enums you may use an in clause as well.

```
status=CUR\TPLN
status_Mod=in
```

Note that the values are separated by a tab.